# Probability density function of $\log(1-|X|/2)$ where $X$ is a uniformly distributed variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm a bit confused on how to solve this. This is my work so far:

[image: problem]

But the last step I have done is apparently wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $|x| > a > 0 \iff x < -a \text { or } x > a$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf P(\lvert X\rvert > n)=\mathsf P(X>n \;\color{blue}\bigcup\; X<-n)$ for any $n>0$

That is: OR not AND.

Comment: Thank you I see my mistake now.

Comment: http://imgur.com/8ibaH1O tihs is the solution, where are the bounds coming from? Why is it a>0 and a<0

Comment: @user3874530 It's fully explained in the image that $\log_e(1-\frac{\lvert X\rvert}{2}) \leq 0$, and hence the support of $f_Y$ is $(-\infty; 0]$.